# How to get all the data rows from DataTables.net when using pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I know I can use the function fnGetData() but that only gets me the data for whichever page I'm on. I want to get all of the data, even from pages not currently displayed. My purpose is to get all of the latitude & longitude fields so that I can display it on a map using Google Maps v3.

I have this code but, again, it only gets me data for the current page.

```
var table = $('#example1 table').dataTable();
            var data = table.fnGetData();   
            console.log(data);
```

Comment: This isn't how it is documented. Suggest creating a demo that shows this behavior

Comment: your code works right away in both 1.9.x and 1.10.x. `fnGetData` with no params returns an array with all rows holding each rows column values as subarrays.

Answer (score 1):

When server-side processing is enabled (`'serverSide': true`), indeed both 1.9.x function [fnGetData()](http://legacy.datatables.net/api#fnGetData) and 1.10.x function [data()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/data%28%29) return data for current page only.

This behavior could be confirmed by viewing [Server-side processing example](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) and running in the console `$('#example').dataTable().fnGetData()` or `$('#example').DataTable().data()`.

In order to retrieve all data, you need to make a separate AJAX request mimicking the behavior of the DataTables.

Since your question is tagged `datatables-1.10` I assume you're using DataTables 1.10.x. You can use [ajax.params()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.params%28%29), that gets the data submitted by DataTables to the server in the last Ajax request.

```
function processAllRecords(){
   var req = $('#example1 table').DataTable().ajax.params();

   // Reset request parameters to retrieve all records
   req.start = 0;
   req.length = -1;
   req.search.value = "";

   // Request data
   $.ajax({
      'url': 'script.php',
      'data': req,
      'dataType': 'json'
   })
   .done(function(json){
      // json.data is array of data source objects (array/object),
      // one for each row
      console.log(json);
   });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use the fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() of the datatable. 
example : http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/2401/record-count-with-server-side-processing
```

I have used it before and I think I could give you a snippet:

```
var table = $('#table ').DataTable(
{
                        "dom" : 'rtp', // Initiate drag column
                        "fnDraw" : false,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "ajax" : ... ...
                            }
                        }),
                      "fnDrawCallback" : drawCallBack,
});

unction drawCallBack() {
    console.log(this.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal());
}
```